# how to mark "executed command" for custom script extension in shell script given

Tags: shell, powershell, azure, virtual-machine

How to mark a configured shell script to executed command in Azure VM Custom Script Extension ?

It is running the shell commands in configured CSE but it has not ending up the script due to one of my command. My command will be running a small HTTP listener kind of server.

If make "exit 0" will mark CSE as command executed and so it will exits in my powershell script where i encountered this CSE.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: @ManVin Only allow HTTP listener service runs on the background.  Am I right. If I am wrong. Please explain what mean `mark a configured shell script to executed command` more detailed. Thanks.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT, thanks for ur help. It worked as expected with ur suggestion using nohup command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is right. You could run HTTP listener in the background and exit your script. Just use below:

```
nohup <bash shell> &
```

> man nohup
>
> nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty
>
> & to the command line to run in the background: